# Moved by nested lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an ul that works fine, but when I add a nested ul the li above, moves. Does anyone know why? how to solve it?

I have the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y5DtE/

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li> first 
        <ul>
             <li> 1.2 </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li> second </li>
  <li> third eally, really long </li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}

ul {
    margin:40px auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0 15px; 
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    color: #666
}

ul li:last-child { margin-right: 0px; }

ul li ul {
    margin:5px 0;
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works. If I understand that you give li position relative to be able that ul ul have position absolute in relation to li. But I still don't understand why without this, li moves?

Comment: because elements position themselves to the bottom of their parent by default; with the first li being bigger, it seems as if the rest of lis position themselves down, when in fact they are on the same baseline. when you use position: absolute, the ul is taken out of li's context and they share the same height again.

Comment: Is there a way to center the nested li or to give them the same with of its parent (when the parent width depends of the width of the word)

Comment: you have to specify the li's width manually, since as of now, your width is calculated by its text content, making it variable. check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CDseb/), i'm using min-width here

Answer (score 1):

To make sublist go under parent element apply this:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

To prevent floating of sub items add the following rule:

```
ul li ul li{
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to put 1.2 below first, not beside. The problem is that "first" moves when I put 1.2

Comment: Ok it solves the problem but then the menu is not centered. If I put your float:left in ul li ul is better. Then the problem comes that the nested is not centered respect its parent. And I still don't understand why without float:left, li moves? Anyway, you solved the first problem. Thank you!.

Comment: it moves because of block behaviour, each block is taking one row by default, without floating. Centering you can achieve with fixed width for each li. Dont forget about answer acception. Stack users hate to work with no return.